# Display the slope of a line graphically

Tags: matlab

Via the code bellow we can construct a set of point and fit a line on them using `polyfit`. The last function returns two variables. The first variable is the slope of the fitted red line. I would like to mark the slope of the fitted line as depicted in the picture bellow using a small black line and a small text showing the slope a. Can you please suggest how we can do it?

```
clear all
close all
clc
x = 0:0.01:2; 
noise = 0.8*randn(size(x));
y = 5*x + noise;
plot(x,y,'ko','MarkerSize', 2)
f = polyfit(x, y, 1) ;
y = f(1)*x + f(2); 
hold on
plot(x,y,'r--','LineWidth',2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
x_start = 1; % or wherever you want the line to start
y_start = 1; % or wherever you want the line to start
x_end = 1.3; % or wherever you want the line to end
y_end = f(1)*(x_end-x_start) + y_start;
line([x_start x_end],[y_start y_end],'Color','k');
text(x_start+0.2,y_start+0.5,['a = ' num2str(f(1))]); % adjust x & y offsets to suit
```